# Replacement of functions bound by sums and integrals in NCAlgebra

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, summation, ncalgebra

I want to use the [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) package to do some simplification on non commutative expressions involving integrals. For example, one such expression would be

$$ I=\left(\int f(x)g(x) dx\right) * h $$

where $*$ denotes non-commutative multiplication. Let's say that I know that $g(x)*h=1$ for all $x$. Then, simplifying the above expression yields

$$ I=\int f(x)dx $$

So far, I have tried the following to implement this in Mathematica:

```
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`

NCReplaceRepeated[(A b[X] F[X]) ** (G h J), b[X_] ** h -> 1]
```

which results in

```
A G J F[X]
```

as expected. However, this does not work for

```
NCReplaceRepeated[(Integrate[A b[X] F[X], X]) ** (G h J), b[X_] ** h -> 1]
```

which results in

```
A G J (Integrate[b[X] F[X], X]) ** h
```

which does not respect this simplification.

Of course, there need to be several assumptions about the integral regarding e.g. convergence. But I want to assume that "everything works out nicely" and that this type of simplification is OK. Additionally, instead of `Integrate`, `Sum` might be used. This simplification does not work either.

How can I properly perform this simplification?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with `Integrate`. The evaluation

```
expr = Integrate[f[X] ** g[X], X] ** h
NCReplaceRepeated[expr, g[X_] ** h -> 1]
```

does not simplify as you expect because `expr` is

> NonCommutativeMultiply[Integrate[NonCommutativeMultiply[f[X],g[X]],X],h]

and `Integrate` is not associative. Check that `Attributes[Integrate]` does not include `Flat`. Therefore, if you want it to associate with your product you have to define a rule for that. For example:

```
expr = Integrate[f[X] ** g[X], X] ** h
NCReplaceRepeated[expr, {Integrate[x_, y_] ** z_ :> Integrate[x ** z, y], g[X_] ** h -> 1}]
```

will evaluate to

> Integrate[f[X],X]

as you want. Note the delayed rule to prevent the simplification of the right-hand side of the rule.

Also be careful with how you operate with `**` with NCAlgebra. The product is non-commutative only if the symbols which it operates on are declared as noncommutative. The above manipulations work because I am using lower cap single letters that are defined to be noncommutative by default. Check out the NCAlgebra documentation for more details.